# Projection from a full-rank PSD manifold to a lower-rank PSD manifold

Tags: matrices, riemannian-geometry

Let $\mathcal{S}_+(n,k) = \{X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}: X=X^\top \succeq 0, \text{rank}(X)=k\}$ be the manifold of positive semidefinite (PSD) matrices. 
I was wondering how to project $X\in \mathcal{S}_+(n,n)$ in a full-rank PSD manifold to a lower-rank PSD manifold $Y\in \mathcal{S}_+(n,k), (k<n)$. Can this projection be obtained by solving

$\arg\min_{Y} ||X-Y||_{\mathtt{F}}, \text{ s.t. rank}(Y)=k $

where $||\cdot||_\mathtt{F}$ is the Frobenius norm? My concern is, if the Frobenius norm is a correct formulation of the projection?

I am not quite familiar with the Riemann geometry, so this question may be stupid.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is to use the singular value decomposition $S=UDU^{-1}$ with $U$ orthogonal and $D$ diagonal with positive decreasing values.  Then replace $D$ by a diagonal matrix $D_k$ whose first $k$ elements in the diagonal are the same as those of $D$ and the others are zero.  Then $S_k=UD_kU^{-1}$ can be defined as the projection.

This solution may not be unique in case of equal eigenvalues.  I am pretty sure that it is equivalent to your argmin formulation.  Note that this is not a *linear* projection.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I understand that the minimization problem can be solved by eigendecomposition. What I am not sure is that if this minimization problem is a correct formulation of projection from $S_+(n,n)$ to  $S_+(n,k)$. I feel that when we talk about Riemann manifold, I should always define a metric first. Is it necessary for my problem?

Comment: @user3138073: I see. There is a Riemannian metric on the set of positive definite matrices. However, you are considering positive semidefinite matrices, which form a cone, with a boundary etc. I am not sure which distance you want to use. The Frobenius metric is commonly used. Perhaps a specialized book can give more ideas.

Comment: While it is tough to me, this paper seems to propose a metrics for semidefinite matrix, https://arxiv.org/pdf/0807.4462.pdf.

Comment: This paper discusses the projection onto a fixed-rank matrix: http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume13/shalit12a/shalit12a.pdf

Answer (score 0):

That is correct. In general, for $n\times n$ matrix $X$ with singular value decomposition $U D V$, the matrix of rank $\le k$ closest to $X$ is 
$X_k= UD_k V$, where $D_k$ is obtained from $D$ by  the smallest $n-k$ diagonal values to $0$. One sees that if $X$ is positive semidefinite, then $X_k$ is also positive semidefinite.

( the distance is given by the Frobenius norm, or any other unitarily invariant norm)

The relevan notion here is : low rank approximation

Comment: Thanks for the comments! My concern is if the Frobenius norm is a proper formulation of the projection. Because, I know that when we work on the Riemann manifold, we should not use Euclidean metric to measure the distance.